# Find the equation to movement with a middle point locked

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, numerical-linear-algebra

I have this scenario:

One particle has to go from $0$ point to $y$ point in $1$ sec.

The particle needs to start moving at time $0$ ($time=0sec$), and to go accelerating until the middle of time ($time=0.5sec$). After this the particle must go slowing down until stops at time 1 ($time=1sec$).

**There is a locked definition problem.:**
Using the defined end point $y$ (if the value is in inch or centimeters doesn't matter here), the particle has to pass at time 0.5 ($time=0.5sec$) in point $y-400$.

To make understanding easier there are two graphic examples below
(the $x$ axis define time and $y$ axis define space):

**Example 1:**
[image]

**Example 2:**
[image]

This is only symbolic graphics, there is no precision in the drawing. These are only to make easy to understand.

PS: the equation is valid only for:
$y \in \mathbb R$
$x \in \mathbb R$
$y > 400$
$x >= 0 \ \&\ x <= 1$

**EDITED**
**The Question:**
I need a formula that defines this movement.

Comment: what exactly is your question? to find a general formula?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Ops, I edited the question, I need a formula that defines this movement.

Comment: But you may find more than one formulas for this, which formula you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

The distance to be travelled is $y$. Suppose in the first half of the time it accelerates with acceleration $a$ and in the second half it decellerates with decelleration $a$. The distance travelled in the first $\frac 12$ seconds is $\frac 18 a^2$ as is the distance travelled in the second $\frac 12$ seconds. The total distance is $\frac 14 a^2$ and $y$, so $a=2\sqrt{y}$.